# How to prevent Firefox from being redirected to https?

Tags: firefox, redirection, https

At work, the net admin. has completely blocked HTTPS for everyone save a few bosses. He claims that way he can be sure no-one is using a proxy, tunnel, etc. to access Facebook, Youtube or other sites deemed not-suitable for work.

The whole web is slowly turning to HTTPS by default. Some sites (like Wikipedia) allow me to go thru simply editing the address and removing the "s", others insist in redirecting me - so I'm cut off of a lot of content I could see otherwise.

I appreciate the webmasters caring about my privacy and security, but such efforts are useless if I cannot use their sites at all as a result.

Is there a way to configure Firefox so it indicates to the site that https cannot/should not be used? Or to set up a proxy to navigate those sites?

Comment: Perhaps using an HTTP tunnel? If they redirect you from the server side, you can't do anything on the client side (no browser plugins and javascript works)

Comment: Have they also blocked SSH? OpenVPN?

Comment: Talk to your it department. We have a squid proxy set up to block https _unless_ the web browser has the proxy server entered. We can see the requests, which is all we care about

Comment: Simply stated.  You can't.  If Facebook configures it website to only accept https there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Note that you can possibly get a FireFox extension to try HTTP instead, but any answer here suggesting a proxy or VPN solution is likely against your company 'Acceptable Use Policy' and you risk some kind of punishment all the way up to losing your job if found out, depending on company strictness. The 'right' answer is to demonstrate to management that this is too strict and stopping your ability to work, or to adequately protect company information, and they can get the net admin to remove the restrictions and/or buy a proper web filter system that can deal with HTTPS as well.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why hes blocked for the reasons hes given as

1. Proxy's rely on http
2. HTTPS is only for web traffic and not much else not vpns as vpns rely on completely different ports

I suggest talking to this net admin who is obviously not very experienced and request that he unblocks port 443 on the grounds of:

- Removing `https` reduces the security of any request to the https site. The most vital being financial transaction or logins to websites.

I'm not sure why removing the `https` port will help anything if it's set up properly.

Comment: the admin possibly wants to track the content that the users are browsing

Comment: @mvark he can do that with out blocking https

Comment: @mvark if this is still a issue after all this time, the admin could generate a selfsigned CA and make SSL certs on the fly and not risk security problems